# Unable to open QGIS after Installation

Tags: qgis

I have a Windows Vista (32 bit) computer.  I tried installing and reinstalling (by uninstalling the software first) QGIS 1.8 a few times then went to version 1.7.4 and still encountering the same problem.

I don't know what the problem is since I am downloading the Windows version of the software.  Could anyone help me with this issue?

Comment: do you get any error-messages?

Answer (score 1):

This is a probable duplicate to the "you need to remove the old local configuration data to upgrade". An easy way to test would be to try it with a new user created on the same machine.

Answer (score 0):

Remove/Rename the offending iconv.dll in C:\WINDOWS ;)